# API call not working on build, but working in development

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

I'm making this API call to the coordinates of the ISS (International Space station)

```
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

then I'm exporting that into my Dashboard.jsx component

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getIssData()
      .then((data) => {
        setIssData(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [issData]);
```

Everything works fine in development but on build I get the error

```
index-83da8be1.js:2830 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://imaginative-
blancmange-b561ab.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an
 insecure resource 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'. This 
request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

So I change it to HTTPS And then I simply get

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Very confused

I am using React once again and this is an ISS Tracker that gets the API of the ISS and plots it real time with the use effect hook on a Cesium JS 3d globe - everything works fine, but I have a conditional

```
{ISS ? {return a bunch of html} : Loading...
```

I removed the ternary to see if it was that and it wasn't

I am stumped y'all :) anything helps

Comment: AFAICT there's no https of that API. It would be valuable to include the **complete** error with reference to the originating source. "Also my logo..." seems like a completely separate question for which no context is provided--it should be asked separately, and actionable details should be provided.

Comment: Sure Dave, I've corrected the question. I removed the logo part of the question and posted the full error - let me know if you can help!

Comment: @DaveNewton I believe you're correct theres no https. am i screwed or how can i solve this? it works in vite in dev but obviously not netlify

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are trying to access a `http` resource while on  `https`. For your situation, you can treat all non-https resources as http by applying this `meta` tag to your html file:

When using Netlify, you can rewrite proxy the non-secure external resource to your app's API. Check out [Proxy to another service](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service) inside of **Rewrites and proxies**. [Here](https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/158#issuecomment-540140129) is a good explanation as well as [here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/requesting-an-http-resource-from-https-website/8510/9).

Save a plain text file called **_redirects** without a file extension to the publish directory of your site containing:

`/api/* http://api.open-notify.org 200!`

Then instead of:

`const response = await fetch('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json')`

You would use:

`const response = await fetch('/api/iss-now.json')`

Comment: So you have asked a loaded question,  that probably IS a problem but it isn't yet because this is an HTTP API not HTTPS so it cant deploy because netlify or firebase wants the SSL.
However I did replace the current third party API with a different one, and set it to run every 1 second

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    getIssData()
      .then((data) => {
        setIssData(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: Revised my answer,. The issue is netlify is served over SSL (`https`)  whereas your local is not (`http`). This error happens when you try to access `http` from `https`.

Comment: sorry if that code isnt formatted correctly i tried as hard as I could, but im using a set interval to call that different api, at a rate of 1 second, which is what was set for the rate limit of that API - but I didnt like that it didnt update as much, and it also ended up overloading anyway, so Im not sure I'm using that setInterval correctly then. The reason its important that it keeps updating is because Its an ISS tracker. the HTTP updates like 2-3 times a second, where the other works on deployment for thirty seconds and then bugs out and is less exciting.

Comment: exactly, and thats what I'm trying to figure out how to fix, I've contacted the owner of the API and asked for an https, but do you know any work arounds? this is just for a project im a junior dev

Comment: No problem. Inside your `index.html` `<head>` tag, try placing the `meta` tag I mentioned. Then it will treat the `http` URL as though it is `https`.

Comment: now im getting error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

its just not loading it now treating it like the errors I get when it deploys, its more like its treating it like its https and just not running it as if its a secure server

Comment: Undo that and check out the revised answer - Netlify has a very specific way of handling non-http resources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251849/discussion-between-timventura-and-wesley-lemahieu).